# How can I differentiate odoo databases according to odoo version?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

In my system I have all those databases which falls under openerp version 7, 8 and 9. I want to differentiate them and take only those databases which falls under odoo version 8. I have checked in postgres files as well as in .openerp-server file. But I didn't get any thing which can help me. How to differentiate the databases?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no obvious place in the database to look for that.

It would be possible to write a script that would inspect the data model looking for known differences between versions to detect the corresponding one.
But no such tool exists at the moment.

Personally, I solve this by always including the version number in the database name, such as `dev-v8` or `dev-v9`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer..

You can execute following query :

SELECT * FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base' AND latest_version like '9.%'